# R and ajax interaction

Tags: ajax, r, web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently process a set of text files using R. The output of this process is a js file, call it: preparedData.js.

I then use preparedData.js as the input to an html file,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/preparedData.js"></script>
```

call it myviz.html which shows a visualization of the data in preparedData.js.

I want to generalize this process so other people can enter their text files on a web page, my R script will prepare the preparedData.js for them, and then provide a link to a new webpage with their visualization on it. So I need to provide a link to a new webage which is a copy of my myviz.html, call it theirviz.html, with the location of their .js file as the input.

I don't have much server interaction experience and I know this is vague but how can I accept the text files as input, launch the R script when they submit the form, and then create the web page with their preparedData.js driving the results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating different html file for every user, you should use a server side scripting language like php. You can create js files with different name for each user. And instead of creating an html page for each user you can create a single php page which takes js file name from session. You can save name of the js file created for a user in session and use it in the php page.

Hope I understood your problem correctly.